# Using tensorflowjs in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tensorflow, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js

I am trying to use tensorflowjs in my chrome extension. But,I am not able to figure out how to do it. I tried to download tf.min.js file by going to this link : https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js
I included this file in the manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage","tabs", "<all_urls>"],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["tf.min.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

As you can see, I've also set content_security_policy to script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'. But, I am always getting multiple warnings in the tf.min.js and errors in the content.js file(Registration of backend webgl failed), which is:

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

bth1.onclick = function scrapeThePage() {
    // Keep this function isolated - it can only call methods you set up in content scripts
    var htmlCode = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    var btn = document.getElementById("mybtn1");

    var keywords = ['a','b','c'];

    var arr = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++){
    var reg = new RegExp(`${keywords[i]}`,'g')
    arr[i] = Math.log(1+(htmlCode.match(reg) || []).length);
    }

  btn.innerText(arr)

}
```

Am I downloading the file from the wrong website? How do I use tensorflowjs in chrome extensions?

Comment: Try their [official extension sample](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/chrome-extension), this may help you how to implement tensorflow js in your extension.

Answer (score 1):

This is the reference I used for my first tensorflowjs code,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.2"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="output_field"></div> 
</body> 
<script> 
    async function learnLinear(){ 
        const model = tf.sequential(); 
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]})); 
        model.compile({ loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd' }); 
        const xs = tf.tensor2d([-2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [7, 1]); 
        const ys = tf.tensor2d([-10,  -7.0, -4.0,-1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0], [7, 1]); 
        await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 500}); 
        document.getElementById('output_field').innerText = model.predict(tf.tensor2d([10, 11], [2, 1])); 
    } 
    learnLinear(); 
</script> 
<html>
```

reference: https://medium.com/tensorflow/getting-started-with-tensorflow-js-50f6783489b2

Comment: I'm not sure whether it works with chrome extensions. It seems to violate a security policy.